# Eigen alignment in nested classes

Tags: c++, class, alignment, eigen

I try to run a program that uses Eigen (3.2.92) compiled with GCC 6.1.1. However, on startup it crashes due to an alignment issue:

```
#3  0x00007ffff4669c82 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x7ffff74319b8 "(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(eigen_unaligned_array_assert_workaround_gcc47(array)) & (31)) == 0 && \"this assertion is explained here: \" \"http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAss"..., file=0x7ffff7431688 "/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h", line=128, function=0x7ffff74340a0 <Eigen::internal::plain_array<double, 4, 0, 32>::plain_array()::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__> "Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 32>::plain_array() [with T = double; int Size = 4; int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]") at assert.c:101
#4  0x00007ffff7399821 in Eigen::internal::plain_array<double, 4, 0, 32>::plain_array (this=0x89ed70) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:128
#5  0x00007ffff739861e in Eigen::DenseStorage<double, 4, 2, 2, 0>::DenseStorage (this=0x89ed70) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:187
#6  0x00007ffff73a7d37 in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >::PlainObjectBase (this=0x89ed70) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:457
#7  0x00007ffff73b3720 in Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>::Matrix (this=0x89ed70) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:259
#8  0x00007ffff73b35a5 in svo::Matcher::Matcher (this=0x89ec90) at /home/user/ros2/catkin_ws/src/rpg_svo/svo/include/svo/matcher.h:106
#9  0x00007ffff73b1b33 in svo::Reprojector::Reprojector (this=0x89ec30, cam=0x884820, map=...) at /home/user/ros2/catkin_ws/src/rpg_svo/svo/src/reprojector.cpp:34
#10 0x00007ffff72e0e62 in svo::FrameHandlerMono::FrameHandlerMono (this=0x89eb10, cam=0x884820) at /home/user/ros2/catkin_ws/src/rpg_svo/svo/src/frame_handler_mono.cpp:37
#11 0x000000000040f70a in svo::VoNode::VoNode() ()
#12 0x000000000040bf05 in main ()
```

These are the relevant code parts:

```
class Matcher {
public:
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  Matrix2d A_cur_ref_;
  Matcher() = default;   // <--- matcher.h:106
};

class Reprojector {
public:
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  Reprojector(...)   // <--- reprojector.cpp:34
  {...}
private:
  Matcher matcher_;
};

class FrameHandlerMono : public FrameHandlerBase {
public:
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  FrameHandlerMono(...) :
    reprojector_(...)   // <--- frame_handler_mono.cpp:37
  {...}
protected:
  Reprojector reprojector_;
};

class VoNode
{
public:
  svo::FrameHandlerMono* vo_;
  VoNode() {
    vo_ = new svo::FrameHandlerMono(...);
  }
};

int main() {
  svo::VoNode vo_node;
  return 0;
}
```

The comments mark the lines where gdb reported the error.

I had a look at the [mentioned website](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html), but I think the EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW macro is involved where required. In addition, I added the macro also to the VoNode class, but that did not fix the error.

**Update**

I compiled the program on a similar machine using GCC 4.8.4 and Eigen 3.2.0 and everything worked just fine. Does the newer GCC (or C++14 as the new default) handle alignment different than the old one?

**Update 2**

I just figured out that Eigen 3.2.92 actually is Eigen 3.3-beta incorporating some [changes](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3). Using Eigen 3.2.8 I have been able to compile and run the software successfully. However, I still have no idea why 3.3 causes those alignment errors.